# Images and css not loading on browsers other than the one set as default for live server in VS Code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, browser, flexbox

I made a static page using HTML and CSS in vs code. Everything is working fine when I view the page in VS COde live server which opens up Mozilla firefox (Which I have set as default for live server). Hower the images does not load when I view the file (index.html) in other browsers. I checked to inspect element which says Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsauI.png)

Comment: How are you accessing it in other browsers?

Comment: Please @Huzaifa add real code into `quotes` instead of an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with its , is path.
You must always use a relative path .
please use relative path so instead of `/img/cloud.png` use `./img/cloud.png`

and also you have used a local file path for `airplane.svg` that wont work.

please provide us with directory structure so that we can help you better.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It cleared up many things for me. I have one other query to discuss. I wnt to add gradient color to my text so i used this css code > .locations-head h3 {
  padding: 4rem 0rem;
  background: linear-gradient(#131c27, #663b34);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

Answer (score -1):

This has nothing to do with the choice of browser.

One of your error messages says it is trying to load the file from your D: drive.

Relative URLs will resolve to different places when the HTML document is loaded from different places.

The URL of the server (`http://localhost:somePort/`) and the URL of the local file (`file://something`) are going to be different.

You need to always load the HTML document from a URL provided by the server. You can't just open the file from your local file system.